# GraphZoomScrollPane scrolling problem

Tags: java, graph, scroll, jung

I'm working with the Jung Framework and got some issues:

I'm painting a graph into a `GraphZoomScrollPane`.
I remark that **it doesn't scroll enough to get all the graph**.
When I add vertices while the window is maximized they don't appear when the window is in a litte size.

*Could anyone help me out please? Is this a bug with the Jung API?*

Comment: GraphZoomScrollPane only acts as the container for `VisualizationViewer`. I think `VisualizationViewer` has its own **viewable limit** which is defined by its dimension (`preferredSize` parameter). For example: `vv =  new VisualizationViewer<Node,Link>(layout, new Dimension(800,400));` It maybe show a graph that falls within this viewable limit. http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/GraphZoomScrollPane.html http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/VisualizationViewer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you've saved me twice :)

Comment: Nice work Jihath. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.